# How to pass the selected dropdown value to a URL in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application and I am using razor syntax. 
I am trying to get the selected item from dropdown list value and to pass it to the controller method.

but I am getting error.

```
The name 'd' does not exist in the current context
```

The Updated Code is...

```
   $("#btnForword").click(function(){
    d = $('#HODList').val()
    alert(d);

    var url2 = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SendPaymentAdviceForApproval", "PaymentAdvice", new { paymentAdviceId = "idValue" , nHOD = "@@D@@" }))"
    url2 = url2.replace("idValue",'@Model.Id');
    url2 = url2.replace("@@D@@",d);

    $.ajax({
        url: url2, type: "POST", success: function (data) {
            $("#btnForword").css("display","none");

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

> Issue solved  Issue solved

The problem in variable 'D' yes in "D".

I checked using inspect element property of Google chrome, when I saw it in console window....
When I click on the button , I can see the string formed in below way

ht...../PaymentAdvice/SendPaymentAdviceForApproval?paymentAdviceId=304&nHO8=D

jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4

see the last character in the above link, it should not be come as a "=D" isnt it ?

I used the below code...and it works perfectly.

```
$("#btnForword").click(function(){

            var url2 = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SendPaymentAdviceForApproval", "PaymentAdvice", new { paymentAdviceId = "idValue" , nHOD = "HODId" }))";
            url2 = url2.replace("idValue",'@Model.Id');
            url2 = url2.replace("HODId",$('#HODList').val());


            $.ajax({
                url: url2, type: "POST", success: function (data) {
                    $("#btnForword").css("display","none");

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Is this a bug in Jquery ?

Comment: You cannot use js variable in server side code...

Comment: you just change your syntax like   d =  document.getElementById("HODList").value; to var  d =  document.getElementById("HODList").value; may be this help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){

$("#btnForword").click(function(){
    var d =  $('#HODList').val();

    var url2 = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SendPaymentAdviceForApproval", "PaymentAdvice", new { paymentAdviceId = "idValue" , nHOD = "@@D@@" }))";
    url2 = url2.replace("idValue",'@Model.Id');
    url2 = url2.replace("@@D@@",d);

    $.ajax({
        url: url2, type: "POST", success: function (data) {
            $("#btnForword").css("display","none");

        }
    });
    return false;
   });
});
```

don't consider replacing "d" as it will affect your other part of url as well.. Try specific placeholder instead.
If this not works... Then can you please show Signature of your Action method too?

Your controller action should be like this

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SendPaymentAdviceForApproval(int paymentAdviceId, int nHOD)
{
   // Your existing logic here... 
}
```

Cheers

Comment: i haven't !!!!
I am using place holder and not the variable in server side code. please undo your down vote

Comment: `nHOD = "#D#"` what is this? this must be selected item value that is named `d`

Comment: Not at all Sir :) it is a place holder which i am using to set value by replace function...  url2 = url2.replace("#D#",d);

Comment: @KD can use D instead of d ?

Comment: Yeah we can.. but a more meaningful name would be preferred instead

Comment: @KD, edit your answer, then I get it back. My vote is locked now. You should edit your question to undo...

Comment: Have you decorated your controller method with [HttpPost] attribute?
you are passing POST request via ajax so it should be decorated properly.

Comment: I am not getting, I just want to send the value of the selected item in url ... Is that so difficult  ?

Comment: we are assigning the d at first statement, d in later parts we are using D ..isnt it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `data` property of `$.ajax` to pass parameter to controller-action.

```
$("#btnForword").click(function(){
    var d =  document.getElementById("HODList").value;

    // define url
    var url2 = 'Url.Action("SendPaymentAdviceForApproval", "PaymentAdvice")';
    //url2 = url2.replace("idValue",'@Model.Id');
    //url2 = url2.replace("d",'@d');

    $.ajax({
        url: url2, 
        type: "POST", 
        // add parameters in here...
        data: { paymentAdviceId : @Model.Id, nHOD : d }
        success: function (data) {
            $("#btnForword").css("display","none");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

And your controller should looks:

```
public ActionResult SendPaymentAdviceForApproval(int paymentAdviceId, int nHOD){...}
```

Comment: d = $('#HODList').val()
            
            var url2 = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SendPaymentAdviceForApproval", what chnages I have to make in this statement ? `"PaymentAdvice", new { paymentAdviceId = "idValue" ,nHOD = "#D#" }))";
            url2 = url2.replace("idValue",'@Model.Id');
            url2 = url2.replace("#D#",d);`

Comment: You want to pass dropdown value to Ur.Action, This is not possible. You can not. `d` is js variable and `Url.Action` is serverside code.

Comment: also no need to use Html.Raw

Comment: What error did you get? Please add your Html codes, and controller-action, too.

Comment: Generating url, and replecing its data is the worst idea to pass parameter with ajax. You should use data property of ajax.

Comment: I have tried your your code , but it shows error, The name 'd' does not exist in the current context...as well bracket is missing...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30684/discussion-between-user1650894-and-aliriza-adiyahsi)