# How to pass the value to URL from dropdown item?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am asking this question again....because I am not getting correct answer...
answers which I get is incorrect.

I am developing MVC application and I am using razor syntax. I am trying to get the selected item from dropdown list value and to pass it to the controller method.

but I am getting error.

```
$("#btnForword").click(function(){
    d =  document.getElementById("HODList").value;

    var url2 = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SendPaymentAdviceForApproval", "PaymentAdvice", new { paymentAdviceId = "idValue" , nHOD = "d" }))";
    url2 = url2.replace("idValue",'@Model.Id');
    url2 = url2.replace("d",'@d');

    $.ajax({
        url: url2, type: "POST", success: function (data) {
            $("#btnForword").css("display","none");

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I think error in this line...

```
   url2 = url2.replace("d",'@d');
```

> Issue solved  Issue solved

The problem in variable 'D' yes in "D".

I checked using inspect element property of Google chrome, when I saw it in console window....
When I click on the button , I can see the string formed in below way

```
  http://localhost:54255/PaymentAdvice/SendPaymentAdviceForApproval?paymentAdviceId=304&nHO8=D

jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
```

see the last character in the above link, it should not be come as a "=D" isnt it ?

I used the below code...and it works perfectly.

```
$("#btnForword").click(function(){

            var url2 = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SendPaymentAdviceForApproval", "PaymentAdvice", new { paymentAdviceId = "idValue" , nHOD = "HODId" }))";
            url2 = url2.replace("idValue",'@Model.Id');
            url2 = url2.replace("HODId",$('#HODList').val());


            $.ajax({
                url: url2, type: "POST", success: function (data) {
                    $("#btnForword").css("display","none");

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Is this a bug in Jquery ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to pass the seelcted dropdown value to URL in MVC ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769607/how-to-pass-the-seelcted-dropdown-value-to-url-in-mvc). _"I am asking this question again....because I am not getting correct answer... answers which I get is incorrect."_ - don't do that, improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable d is not a server variable that can be called with "@" but a client variable set in javascript, so it should be user like :

```
$("#btnForword").click(function(){
    d =  document.getElementById("HODList").value;

    var url2 = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SendPaymentAdviceForApproval", "PaymentAdvice", new { paymentAdviceId = Model.Id , nHOD = "d" }))";
    url2 = url2.replace("d",d);

    $.ajax({
        url: url2, type: "POST", success: function (data) {
            $("#btnForword").css("display","none");

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

(and the "@Model.Id" can be called directly in the Url.Action method).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. The problem is that the js replace function replaces every "d" character contained in the url2 string with your @d variable!!!
You need to replace the "d" identifier with something that does not appear twice (or more) in the url string. Besides, I think is better if you create the url directly using javascript and not the Razor helper. You can do this in one line of code instead of three. Regards.

Comment: ya, you are right...I am supposed to read your answer , but I don't... I waste my day.... thanks...